# Engineering partial differential equation with one non-homogeneous boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for a function $u(x,t)$ on the domain $[0,L]$ and $[0,+\infty]$, that satisfies the PDE:
$$u_t=\alpha u_{xx}$$
Initial condition:
$$u(x,0)=a$$
First boundary condition:
$$u(0,t)=0$$
Second boundary condition:
$$u_x(L,t)=bu(L,t)+c$$
$\alpha, a, b$ and $c$ are Real constants.

Ansatz:
$$u(x,t)=X(x)\Gamma(t)$$
Separation of variables:
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}=\frac{X''}{X}=-\lambda^2$$
Two ODEs:
$$\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}=-\alpha\lambda ^2$$
$$X''+\lambda^2X=0\tag{1}$$
$(1)$ solves to:
$$X(x)=c_1\cos \lambda x+c_2\sin \lambda x$$
With the first BC:
$$u(0,t)=0\implies X(0)=0 \implies c_1=0$$
$$X(x)=c_2\sin \lambda x$$
Translating the second BC:
$$\Gamma X'(L)=b\Gamma X(L)+c$$
Which is basically where I get stuck.

---

I'm not sure if it helps but the *steady state* solution for:
$$u_t=0$$
$$\implies\frac{\mathrm{d^2}u}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=0$$
Which solves to:
$$u(x)=c_3x+c_4$$
Using the first BC:
$$u(0)=0\implies c_4=0\implies u(x)=c_3x$$
Translating the second BC:
$$u'(L)=bu(L)+c$$
$$c_3=bc_3L+c$$
$$c_3=\frac{c}{1-bL}$$
$$u(x)=\frac{c}{1-bL}x$$